# Should Nuget packages perform CRUD operations on the database?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

At work we are thinking of creating Nuget packages for all of our current libraries. Some that perform CRUD operations. **Are there any standards that says anything against or in favor of having Nuget Packages perform CRUD operations?** Some at work raised objections to it on the grounds that nuget packages should not be performing CRUD operations.

Comment: Would you be nugetizing the infrastructure that wraps a CRUD operation(for SQL all the connection and command instantiation and execution), or the actual commands, or both?

Comment: @NathanWerry these nuget would only have the business logic and the data access layer. The connections would be injected in.

Comment: I doubt there are standards against that. But I would think you would only benefit from that if you had more than one presentation layer consuming the nugets.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything against using nuget for CRUD operation, in fact it is good idea if you are working in new agile project where you will have progressive updates to code. Here nuget can make sure you have version of you DAL layer that can support existing code for testing at old version & development in new version .

Also if later you want to replace Database technology later(like moving from SQL server on-prem to Sql Azure/Cosmos) only new CRUD nuget package version for same business entites with same contract can work without changes.

I can't see anything against it apart from fact it makes debugging hard as nuget are release version & you can't step into code on exception while debugging so make sure you have extensive logging & exception handling.